# Laravel, blade y jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, blade

Edito porque planteé mal la pregunta.

Tengo una duda con el parent de jquery y blade en laravel.

tengo los siguientes archivos (blade vista principal, blade modal)

La vista principal hace un extends de la modal, para llamar luego esa modal.

Ahi mismo en la vista principal hay un script jquery el cual dentro de su funcion principal tiene un @parent

```
 // Arriba 
    @extends(modal.blade.php)
    
   // Abajo
    
   // .... otros scripts (jquery, datatables, bootstrap, etc)
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        /... codigo jquery aquí

        @parent
    
    });
    
    </script>
```

la cuestion es que quiero llevar todo ese script a otro archivo JS el cual luego llamo a la vista principal al final de los demas scripts con su ruta normal y lo reconoce sin problema.

Con lo cual la vista principal quedaria mas o menos asi

```
   // Arriba 
    @extends(modal.blade.php)
   
   // Abajo
    
    .... otros scripts (jquery, datatables, bootstrap, etc)
    
    <script src="El nuevo archivos js"></script>
```

y el sistema ya con tres archivos en este caso (vista principal, vista de modal y fichero de script)

La cuestión esta en que el @parent que función en el script cuando esta en blade me funciona bien pero cuando lo llevo a fichero aparte JS ya no me lo permite.

Cuando saco el javascript al archivo aparte la ventana modal deja de funcionar, ese es exactamente el problema. Los plugins comodatepicker y demas que estan en la vista principal funcionan correctamente, solo es la modal

Como puedo solucionar este tipo de problemas

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una cosa, te creas un partial con los includes de jquery y librerias base que quieras por ejemplo:

`libs.js`

```
<script>...<script> //jquery
```

y en la vista main (`app.blade`) pues pones abajo del todo

```
@include('lugar.donde.hayas.guardado.libs)
```

debajo de esto  un section especifico de cada vista:

```
@section('js-especifico')
```

y en las vistas hijas:

```
@extends('app...')

@section('js-especifico')

 <script> logica de lo q sea q influya unicamente a esta vista</script>
@endsection('js-especifico')
```

## Edición después del comentario a esta respuesta:

---

Si he entendido bien tienes un js externo, que quieres poner solo en una vista, en vez de poner el propio script en la vista, pues haz lo siguiente:

Partiendo de que tienes un fichero : `hagoAlgo.js` en `public/js/hagoAlgo.js` y quieres usarlo en una vista en concreto, haz lo siguiente:

En la vista hija añades el script de esta manera:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/hagoAlgo.js') }}" ></script>
```

Esto buscara en el directoriio `public\js\` de tu app de laravel. Donde deberias tener este fragmento de js que quieres incluir.

Comment: Gracias amigo, si se me olvido mencionar esa parte , lesta hecho asi una vista con todos los script base que usara toda la app y luego la section especifica de scripts de cada vista segun su necesidad. Y el problema me sale en la parte especifica, que queremos manejarla desde archivo externo y no metido en el blade.

Comment: @Adrian he editado mi respuesta a lo que  creo que preguntas, mira a ver si no la vuelvo a editar

Comment: nuevamente muchas gracias. A ver que creo que no supe explicar algo bien, y lo aclaro tengo la vista del modal y la principal , la principal llama a la modal con extends(vista-modal).  luego tengo el script dentro de la principal y funciona la modal perfectamente, ese script tiene un parent como lo mente arriba. cuando me llevo todo el script al fichero externo  unicamente la modal no funciona lo demas si y el parent no me lo deja usar alli y cuando pongo el parent en la principal despues de llamar el archivo pues no sirve. No se si me he aclarado ahora mejor. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Todo se llama correctamente el extends con su arroba y el parent tambien solo que no me deja poner dos arrobas el comentario

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer un push en las vistas en donde deseas usar JS. ASi no tendrias problema.

```
@push('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

Asi no tendrias problema.